# Jquery header load not showing menu

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to load Header and Footer. I have done three websites that way so far but I am having problem with this fourth one. The navigation menu is not loading.

http://www.calgarytrackcouncil.com/header.html

http://www.calgarytrackcouncil.com/meets.html
Thanks,

Comment: Are you referring to the `#offcanvas-menu`?

Comment: As soon as your website changes, this question becomes useless for future readers. I recommend reading [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question with the code relevant to the problem you're having.

Comment: Looks like `.fh5co-header-section` is `position:absolute`, which removes it from the document flow. As a result, `#fh5co-header` has no height and the content doesn't show.

Comment: You can see the menu here http://www.calgarytrackcouncil.com/index.html where I am not using the jquery loader. I am a bit over my head, if the problem is found I would also need the solution. Seems to me that the header loads, but something is interfering with loading the menu.